# Finding "expire" Unix timestamp in Google Aerial View URI

Tags: google-maps, google-aerial-view-api

I am using Google Aerial View API which returns various video URIs and image. The video URI includes two "expire" questString parameters. The one I need is a Unix timestamp, for example: "expire=1692293409". I would like to extract it so I can prevent new page requests before the URI expires.

The problem I'm facing is that I cannot get the "expire=" from the queryString parameter without including all of the URI that precedes it. I should state that the URI sub domain changes. Faced with this issue, I will defer to using a regular expression, but I really wanted to see if anyone knows a better way of getting it without regex.

See snippets.

```js
const str = `https://rr3---sn-ab5sznzr.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1692293409&ei=LVfeZPznBNzVxtYP6fGumA4&ip=0.0.0.0&id=eec1090000000001&itag=375&source=aerial_view&requiressl=yes&mh=zr&mm=31&mn=sn-ab5sznzr&ms=au&mv=D&mvi=3&pl=0&susc=av&acao=yes&mime=video/mp4&vprv=1&gir=yes&clen=37334381&dur=40.016&lmt=1692284379956793&mt=1692291598&txp=0011224&sparams=expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,requiressl,susc,acao,mime,vprv,gir,clen,dur,lmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRQIgJ9ezr5eQ8xNpByTUxt_S4HolCWoKivvl0ZxcWVvibhsCIQCLMqUVagEZ6Ny_f1Y5FCyiasgDqMKSt_anfCENFP0ncA==&lsparams=mh,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl&lsig=AG3C_xAwRAIgDFbq7O72r5X9G4oHwCFiDBKT__iYM3ihykSfAVHqzqUCICBt729v5DhYv0teMRVo0xJfS4mFGP2chtrbGqBwixzr`;

const regex = /(\bexpire=)\w+[^&]/gm;

let match;
while ((match = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (match.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    if (match !== null) {       
        let arr = match[0].split("=");
        console.log(arr[1]);
    } else {
        console.log("false");
    }
}
```

> `"https://rr3---sn-ab5sznzr.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire="`

For example, "expire" is not returned in queryString

// console.log(searchParams.has("expire"));

```js
const str = `https://rr3---sn-ab5sznzr.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1692293409&ei=LVfeZPznBNzVxtYP6fGumA4&ip=0.0.0.0&id=eec1090000000001&itag=375&source=aerial_view&requiressl=yes&mh=zr&mm=31&mn=sn-ab5sznzr&ms=au&mv=D&mvi=3&pl=0&susc=av&acao=yes&mime=video/mp4&vprv=1&gir=yes&clen=37334381&dur=40.016&lmt=1692284379956793&mt=1692291598&txp=0011224&sparams=expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,requiressl,susc,acao,mime,vprv,gir,clen,dur,lmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRQIgJ9ezr5eQ8xNpByTUxt_S4HolCWoKivvl0ZxcWVvibhsCIQCLMqUVagEZ6Ny_f1Y5FCyiasgDqMKSt_anfCENFP0ncA==&lsparams=mh,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl&lsig=AG3C_xAwRAIgDFbq7O72r5X9G4oHwCFiDBKT__iYM3ihykSfAVHqzqUCICBt729v5DhYv0teMRVo0xJfS4mFGP2chtrbGqBwixzr`;

const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(str);

for (const p of searchParams) {
    console.log(`${p}\n`);
}
```